# Alerting on the last iteration of a Loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi So ive read threw a whole bunch of the questions in regards to this.. Most of them throw off my data or I just cant get them to actually proc on the last iteration

```
for(const[m, value] of datesLess) {
          console.log("Logging M:" + m);
        
            if(startD == m || endD == m){
              console.log(m)
              takendates.push(m);
              if (m === datesLess.length - 1) {
                    alert("The following Bookings are taken:"+takendates.join("\n"));
              }
            }else{
              this.logentry(startDay,startMonth,startYear,endDay,endMonth,endYear,entryinfo);
            }
          }
```

In essence im trying to display the alert on the last iteration of the loop so the user can see which dates are incorrect as to just displaying a popup with no details

Comment: Why are you not just showing the alert _after_ the loop (assuming `takendates` has a length>1)? Currently this will only work if the last iteration happens to enter the `if` condition which is probably not what you want

Comment: you know what I dint think of that you 100% right

Comment: See my answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure what you really want to be doing is showing the alert *after* the loop

```
const takenDates = [];
for(const[m, value] of datesLess) {
  console.log("Logging M:" + m);
    
  if(startD == m || endD == m){
     console.log(m)
     takendates.push(m);
  }else{
     this.logentry(startDay,startMonth,startYear,endDay,endMonth,endYear,entryinfo);
  }
}
if(takendates.length) {
    alert("The following Bookings are taken:"+takendates.join("\n"));
}
```